# Outlook open add-in when email was sent or the sent button is clicked

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Anyone has an idea when i click the send button, It will call the sample outlook plugin i created?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko so when i click the send button nor when sending an email, after i sent it. The custom taskpane ive created will be open.

Comment: That is not possible. You need to use a ribbon button or add a notification item where users may click to open a task pane. See my post and comments there for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The yeoman generator doesn't scaffold add-in solutions that handle the `ItemSend` or `Launch events` out of the box. So, you need to add such functionality on your own after scaffolding a skeleton.

There are basically two main ways of handling the `Send` button clicks in Outlook web add-ins:

1. The `on-send` feature or so-called the `ItemSend` event. The on-send feature for Outlook add-ins provides a way to handle a message or meeting item, or block users from certain actions, and allows an add-in to set certain properties on send. The event allows displaying custom dialog windows in Outlook for processing the users input.
2. Another option is [Smart Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough) which is a newer version of the on-send feature. It was released in [requirement set 1.12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/requirement-set-1.12/outlook-requirement-set-1.12) and introduced the `OnMessageSend` and `OnAppointmentSend` events. Similar to the on-send feature, `Smart Alerts` enables your add-in to check that certain conditions are met before a mail item is sent. `Smart Alerts` differentiates itself from the on-send feature as follows:

   - It offers send mode options when you want to provide your users with optional recommendations instead of mandatory conditions.
   - It allows your add-in to be published to `AppSource` if the manifest's `SendMode` property is set to the `SoftBlock` or `PromptUser` option. For more information on the differences between `Smart Alerts` and the `on-send` feature, see [Differences between Smart Alerts and the on-send feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough#differences-between-smart-alerts-and-the-on-send-feature).

Comment: Hi @eugene, Thanks for this. How do i trigger the add-in? Some example that i need to create a dialog. I dont want it. I want to trigger the custom addin and the sidepanel appear magically.  Any advice?

Comment: The task pane can't be opened programmatically. The best what you could do is to open a task pane by clicking on the ribbon button or by clicking on the notification item which could also open a task pane. Consider displaying a dialog box instead, see [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) for more information.